# Sidebar Menu not functioning as planned using setActiveChildItem for Next Js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am trying to use the setActiveChildItem function to keep a child menu open when the user clicks on a child item in a sidebar menu. However, the child menu is closing when I click on a child item.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
const handleMenuItemClick = (name, href) => {
if (href) {
setCurrentMenuItem(href);
setActiveChildItem(name);
} else if (name === currentMenuItem) {
setActiveChildItem(activeChildItem === name ? '' : name);
} else {
setCurrentMenuItem(name);
setActiveChildItem(name);
}
};
```

I have tried adding a console.log statement to the handleMenuItemClick function to track what is happening, but the console is not logging anything.

I am not sure what is wrong with my code. Can anyone help me?

Here is the full code for the SidebarMenu component:

```
import { Disclosure } from '@headlessui/react';
import { ChevronRightIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const navigation = [
 {
   name: 'Racing',
   children: [
     { name: 'Horse Racing', href: '/racing/horses' },
     { name: 'Greyhound Racing', href: '/racing/greyhounds' },
     { name: 'Harness Racing', href: '/racing/harness' },
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'Aussie Rules',
   children: [
     { name: 'AFL', href: '/aussie-rules/afl' },
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'Basketball',
   children: [
     { name: 'NBA', href: '/basketball/nba' },
     { name: 'NBL', href: '/basketball/nbl' },
     { name: 'NCAAB', href: '/basketball/ncaab' },
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'Baseball',
   children: [
     { name: 'MLB', href: '/baseball/mlb' },
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'Rugby League',
   children: [
     { name: 'NRL', href: '/rugby-league/nrl' },
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'US Football',
   children: [
     { name: 'NFL', href: '/us-football/nfl' },
     { name: 'NCAAF', href: '/us-football/ncaaf' },
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'Soccer',
   children: [
     { name: 'A-League', href: '/soccer/a-league' },
     { name: 'Bundesliga', href: '/soccer/bundesliga' },
     { name: 'Premier League', href: '/soccer/epl' },
     { name: 'Serie A', href: '/soccer/serie-a' },
     { name: 'La Liga', href: '/soccer/la-liga' },
     { name: 'Ligue 1', href: '/soccer/ligue-1' },
     { name: 'Champions League', href: '/soccer/champions-league' },
     { name: 'Europa League', href: '/soccer/europa-league' },
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'Ice Hockey',
   children: [
     { name: 'NHL', href: '/ice-hockey/nhl' },
   ],
 },
 // Other navigation items...
];

function classNames(...classes) {
 return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');
}

export default function SidebarSportsMenu({ currentMenuItem, setCurrentMenuItem }) {
 const [activeChildItem, setActiveChildItem] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
   const parentMenuItem = navigation.find((item) =>
     item.children.some((child) => child.href === currentMenuItem)
   );

   if (parentMenuItem) {
     setActiveChildItem(parentMenuItem.name);
   } else {
     const childMenuItem = navigation.find((item) =>
       item.children.some((child) => child.href === currentMenuItem)
     );

     if (childMenuItem) {
       setActiveChildItem(childMenuItem.name);
     }
   }
 }, [currentMenuItem]);

 const handleMenuItemClick = (name, href) => {
   if (href) {
     setCurrentMenuItem(href);
     setActiveChildItem(name);
   } else if (name === currentMenuItem) {
     setActiveChildItem(activeChildItem === name ? '' : name);
   } else {
     setCurrentMenuItem(name);
     setActiveChildItem(name);
   }
 };

 return (
   <div className="flex flex-col h-full">
     <div className="border-b border-gray-200 bg-blue px-4 py-2 sm:px-0">
       <h4 className="text-base font-semibold leading-2 text-white">Coverage</h4>
     </div>
     <nav className="flex flex-1 flex-col mt-5">
       <ul role="list" className="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-y-7">
         <li>
           <ul role="list" className="-mx-2 space-y-1">
             {navigation.map((item) => (
               <li key={item.name}>
                 {!item.children ? (
                   <a
                     href={item.href}
                     className={classNames(
                       'group flex gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-base leading-6 font-bold',
                       {
                         'bg-[#47566d] text-gray-800': currentMenuItem === item.href,
                         'bg-[#47566d] text-white hover:bg-[#a3aab6] hover:text-[#1a2c49]': currentMenuItem !== item.href,
                       }
                     )}
                     onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick(item.name, item.href)}
                   >
                     {item.name}
                   </a>
                 ) : (
                   <Disclosure as="div" defaultOpen={activeChildItem === item.name}>
                     {({ open }) => (
                       <>
                         <Disclosure.Button
                           className={classNames(
                             activeChildItem === item.name
                               ? 'bg-[#30415b] text-zinc-100'
                               : 'bg-[#1a2c49] text-white hover:bg-[#47566d] hover:text-zinc-100',
                             'flex items-center w-full text-left square-md p-2 gap-x-3 text-base leading-6 font-semibold'
                           )}
                           onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick(item.name, null)}
                         >
                           {item.name}
                           <ChevronRightIcon
                             className={classNames(
                               'ml-auto h-5 w-5',
                               { 'text-[#1a2c49]': open, 'text-gray-400': !open }
                             )}
                             aria-hidden="true"
                           />
                         </Disclosure.Button>
                         {open && (
                           <Disclosure.Panel as="ul" className="mt-1 px-0">
                             {item.children.map((subItem) => (
                               <li key={subItem.name}>
                                 <a
                                   href={subItem.href}
                                   className={classNames(
                                     currentMenuItem === subItem.href
                                       ? 'bg-[#a3aab6] text-zinc-800'
                                       : 'bg-[#47566d] text-zinc-100 hover:bg-[#a3aab6] hover:text-zinc-800',
                                     'flex items-center block square-md py-2 pr-2 pl-3 text-sm leading-6 font-semibold'
                                   )}
                                   onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick(subItem.name, subItem.href)}
                                 >
                                   {subItem.name}
                                 </a>
                               </li>
                             ))}
                           </Disclosure.Panel>
                         )}
                       </>
                     )}
                   </Disclosure>
                 )}
               </li>
             ))}
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </div>
 );
}
```

here is the code for the index.js where the sidebar menu is imported.

```
import '../../../app/globals.css';
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import SidebarSportsMenu from '../../../components/layout/SidebarSportsMenu';
import HorsesEventsCurrentTable from '../../../components/events/racing/HorsesCurrentEventsTable';
import ResponsibleGambling from '../../../components/layout/ResponsibleGambling'
import PageHeader from '@/components/layout/PageHeader';
import HorsesPreviewTemplate from './event';
import CountrySelect from '../../../components/layout/CountrySelect'
import Footer from '@/components/layout/Footer';
import HorsesHome from './HorsesHome';

export default function HorsesHomepage() {
 const [currentMenuItem, setCurrentMenuItem] = useState('Horse Racing');
 const [selectedEventId, setSelectedEventId] = useState(null);

 const handleMenuItemClick = (name) => {
   setCurrentMenuItem(name);
   setSelectedEventId(null);
 };

 const handleEventSelection = (eventId) => {
   setSelectedEventId(eventId);
 };


 return (
   <>
     <div className="flex flex-col">
       <div className="flex min-h-full flex-col">
         <PageHeader />
         <header className="shrink-0 border-b pt-0 pb-3 border-neutral bg-[#14233a]">
         <div className="mx-auto flex h-16 max-w-7xl justify-end px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
         <CountrySelect />
       </div>

         </header>
         <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-7xl mt-2.5">
           <ResponsibleGambling />
         </div>
         <div className="mx-auto flex w-full max-w-7xl items-start gap-x-2 px-4 py-5 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
           <aside className="top-8 hidden w-48 shrink-0 lg:block bg-[#1a2c49] h-screen px-4 py-1">
             {/* SIDEBAR MENU - LEFT */}
             <SidebarSportsMenu currentMenuItem={currentMenuItem} setCurrentMenuItem={handleMenuItemClick} />
           </aside>
           <main className="sticky top-8 w-full lg:w-96 shrink-0 bg-white overflow-y-auto h-screen hide-scrollbar">
             {/* EVENT LIST DETAILS HERE */}
             <div className="mt-0">
               <HorsesEventsCurrentTable handleEventSelection={handleEventSelection} selectedEventId={selectedEventId} />
             </div>
           </main>
           <aside className="flex-1 w-[calc(100%-5rem)] lg:w-[calc(100%-18rem)] bg-white overflow-y-auto hide-scrollbar h-screen p-0">
             {/* EVENT PREVIEWS HERE */}
             {selectedEventId ? (
               <HorsesPreviewTemplate eventUrl={`/racing/horses/event/${selectedEventId}`} />
             ) : (
               <HorsesHome />
             )}
           </aside>
         </div>
         <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-7xl mb-3.5">
           <ResponsibleGambling />
         </div>
         
       </div>
       <Footer />
     </div>
   </>
 );
}
```